# Issue with Implementing an interface which is in a separate class library

Tags: vb.net

I have the following two class libraries:

A - First library - Code below:Saved as *MyInterface.dll*

```
Public Class InterfaceHolder
    Interface IMaths
        Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    End Interface
End Class
```

B = Second class library. Code is as follows: B references A

```
Imports MyInterface
Public Class MathOperations
    Implements InterfaceHolder.IMaths
    Public Function ADD(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer Implements InterfaceHolder.IMaths.ADD
        Return a + b
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem I am facing:
In B when I change the function name from ADD to something else I am not getting any error. I am expecting an error in such a situation as the name in the implementation and the interface should match. But thats not the case. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the name should match? The problem seems to be in your expectations, not the compiler.

Comment: If the signature remains the same and  `Implements InterfaceHolder.IMaths.ADD` also remains the same (you're not renaming it to follow the method's name), it's the same implementation.

Comment: VB allows the implementation of an interface item to have a different name from the interface item.  That is, you are allowed to have `Public Sub Qwerty() Implements IMyInterface.Dvorak ...`.  The behavior is by design, and as long as you are working through variables typed as the interface (rather than the concrete implementation), it should be transparent to you.